# Qual è l'uso corretto dei verbi in queste frasi?

Tags: verbs, grammar

Quale delle seguenti costruzioni è corretta?

1. "... un pranzo che mi piacerebbe organizzare presso di voi e che
   anche per voi rappresenterebbe un'opportunità..."
   oppure
2. "... un pranzo che mi piacerebbe organizzare presso di voi e che
   anche per voi potrebbe rappresentare un'opportunità..."

Comment: Entrambe le frasi sono corrette. La prima e più assertiva della seconda. Qual è il dubbio?